# How to access many to many mapped table in c# with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using EF code-first. I have two classes `Users` and `Roles` which are mapped in a many-to-many relationship as below.

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLoggedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordChangedOn { get; set; }
    public int IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        HasMany(r => r.Roles).WithMany(u=>u.Users)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("UserRoles");
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
            });
    }
}
```

Now I want to fetch `RoleName` from `Roles` with respective to `UserId` from `Users`

I am using this code:

```
var roleName = db.Users.Join(db.UserRoles, u => u.UserId, r => r.UserId, (u, r) => new { u, r })
                       .Join(db.Roles, ur => ur.r.RoleId, q => q.RoleId, (ur, q) => new { ur, q })
                       .Where(m => m.ur.r.UserId == 1)
                       .Select(m => new { m.ur.r.UserId, m.q.RoleName });
```

But it does not allow me to use `UserRoles`.

Error

> 'Context' does not contain a definition for 'UserRoles' and no extension method 'UserRoles' accepting a first argument of type 'Context' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: These are navigation properties, why don't you just use `.Include` instead? `db.Users.Include("Roles").Where(...`. Whole point of EF is that relationships are modeled for you, you don't need to join, that's automatic. In fact you don't even need include if you don't need the role object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the table you define in the fluent API will only be used (and known) by the database. From your application, you should query it by doing :

```
db.Users.Find(userId).SelectMany(x=>x.Roles).SelectMany(x=>x.RoleName)
```

Note that this will load all Roles from the user in memory, but this is fine since you will never have 1000 roles for one user I guess.

Apart from that, I think that you should only have a 1 to 1 relationship between Roles and Users. I'd advise to add a UserId column in the role class and to remove the Users collection from this class.

This way, your query will simply be :

```
db.Roles.Where( x => x.UserId = userId).Select( x => x.RoleName);
```

And this time, only the Role Names will be pulled into memory. I think it is also a slightly better design.

Comment: `@red2nb`- Below query works for me

`db.Users.Find(userId).Roles.FirstOrDefault()`
Thanks for your answer.